# mysql_fetch_array only running once, should be six

Tags: php, mysql

I can see in my logcat that the **$check** query is only running once, when it should be running once for every result of the **$result** query, which is 6. I've been troubleshooting this for hours and I just can't figure out why it's not working properly.

Is there an obvious reason why **$check** is only running once?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE facebook_id = $fbid ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    $mytime = $row1['time'];
    $mylat = $row1['latitude'];
    $mylon = $row1['longitude'];
    $mypostid = $row1['id'];

    // get all products from products table
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT facebook_id as fid, id as uid,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `time`, '$mytime') AS timediff
        FROM `posts`
        WHERE `facebook_id` != $fbid
        HAVING `timediff` <= '180'
        ORDER BY `time` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0) 
    {
        $response["products"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) 
        {
            // temp user array
            $product = array();
            $product["facebookid"] = $row["fid"];
            $product["timediff"] = $row["timediff"];
            $product["theirpostid"] = $row["uid"];
            $product["mypostid"] = $mypostid;

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }
    }
}
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Just an advice: don't do that. It's really a bad idea to join tables using php - use mysql joins or nested queries.

Comment: @pkelly what is the output of `mysql_num_rows($check)` ?

Comment: It outputs 6, which is the correct amount of rows that should be showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because you set

`$response["products"] = array();`

inside every cycle. Move it out of this inner `while`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're correct. I just tried that and the result changed drastically. It's complicated so I'm going to test some things, but I think that was correct. Thanks!

Comment: @pkelly make sure that you move array declarations outside while loops unless and otherwise intended